# ¿Poque debo cerrar una Conexión a mi base de Datos desde java?

Tags: java

Alguien podría decirme porque es necesario cerrar una conexión de la base de datos desde java, osea que pasaría si no lo cierro, acaso la misma no se cierra automáticamente?.

Answer (score 10):

Existe una forma de cerrar las conexiones automáticamente, pero por alguna razón pasa desapercibida y solo unos pocos hacen uso de esta novedad.

**Java try with resources**, incorporada en Java 7, permite una gestión del cierre de recursos mucho más sencilla (automática), dicho de otra manera, es un nuevo mecanismo de manejo de excepciones que facilita el cierre correcto de recursos que se utilizan dentro de un bloque `try-catch`.

En lugar de tener esto:

```
Connection conn = null;
Statement stmt = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
try {
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:mem:test", "", "");
    stmt = conn.createStatement();
    rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM INFORMATION");
    while (rs.next()) {
        System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
    }
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.getCause();
} finally {
    if (rs != null) {
        try {
            rs.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.getCause();
        }
    }
    if (stmt != null) {
        try {
            stmt.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.getCause();
        }
    }
    if (conn != null) {
        try {
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.getCause();
        }
    }
}
```

El código es realmente duro.

Gracias a Java 7 y a la estructura de **try-catch-with resources** podemos simplificarlo a lo siguiente:

```
try(Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:mem:test", "sa", "");
    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM INFORMATION")) {
        while (rs.next()) {
           System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
        }
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.getCause();
}
```

Las variables `Connection`, `Statement` y `ResultSet` son creadas en la sentencia `try` y después de que se iteren sobre todos los resultados, cuando el bloque termina, la JVM automáticamente cierra todos los recursos.

Las ventajas son evidentes y el código es mucho mas sencillo de gestionar, reduciendo bastante el número de líneas y también se elimina el bloque `finally` para el cierre de recursos.

Puedes investigar más sobre esta novedad en la documentación oficial [aquí](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html). Espero haberte ayudado con tu duda y haberte guiado a que utilices las nuevas técnicas que se han implementado para todos.

Comment: Gracias por enfatizar esta buena práctica.

Answer (score 9):

Puesto que una conexión con una base de datos consume muchos recursos, siempre se recomienda cerrarla cuando finalizas el proceso que estes realizando, tanto si ha sido ejecutado con exito o no, puesto que Java no cierra las conexiones automáticamente.

Es recomendable que lo pongas dentro de un bloque finally

```
try {
    // Código a ejecutar

} catch(Exception ex) {
    // Administrar las excepciones

} finally {
    conn.close();
}
```

Comment: Pero eso debo realizarlo solo al cerrar mi aplicacion?

Comment: Al cerrar la aplicación, la conexión se finalizará sola, puesto que la base de datos se dara cuenta de que la comunicación con la aplicación se ha perdido, cerrarla se debe hacer cuando accedas a la base de datos por algún motivo (leer registros, escribir, etc) despues de finalizar dicha consulta (query), debes cerrar la conexión.

Comment: Si cierro la conexión, entonces ya no puedo realizar consultas a la base de datos, obtengo el error: No operations allowed after Connection closed.

Comment: Exacto, como ha dicho @lois6b, la abres cuando la necesites y la cierras cuando no, de esa manera optimizas recursos.

Comment: Ahhh ya lo entendi, muchas gracias por su tiempo.

Answer (score 4):

Es importante enfatizar que la razón por la cual debes cerrar la conexión a la base de datos es porque **si mantienes abierta una conexión de base de datos consume recursos en la base de datos, memoria y las bases de datos están configuradas para tener un número máximo de conexiones, por lo que aumenta la probabilidad de quedarse sin conexiones.**

Por esta razón principalmente  El cliente obtiene conexiones, las usa y luego debe liberarlas cuando termina, lo cual es lo recomendable.

¿Que sucede si olvidas cerrar la conexión?, en  este caso, el Garbage Collector (recolector de basura) de java cerrará la conexión cuando limpie los objetos obsoletos.

Para terminar la conexión, esta debe ser cerrada explícitamente llamando el método [close()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#close())

> [Close()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#close()): Libera la base de datos de este objeto Connection y los
> recursos JDBC de forma inmediata en lugar de esperar que se liberen
> automáticamente.

---

#### Como cerrar una base de datos:

```
try {

connection = dataSource.getConnection();

//Realiza tarea usando la conexión que realizo.

} finally {
   //Cierra la conexión.
   connection.close();
}
```